# Call Waiting Spinner Via Arguments In Batch Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I wanted to call waiting spinner on my batch script like this is my code:

```
@echo off
::-----------------------------Waiting-Spinner-------------------------------
:spinner
set mSpinner=%mSpinner%.
if %mSpinner%'==....' (set mSpinner=.)
cls
::----------------------------Subdomain-Script-------------------------------
echo Enumerating Subdomains From Script1 %mSpinner%
python2 enumsubdomain.py google.com > google.txt
SLEEP 1
goto spinner
echo Enumerating Subdomains From Script2 %mSpinner%
python2 enumsubdomain2.py yahoo.com > yahoo.txt
SLEEP 1
goto spinner
@pause
```

And this spinner text output should be something like this:

```
Enumerating Subdomains From Script1 ...<Here this dot will be animated]
Enumerating Subdomains From Script2 ...<Here this dot will be animated]
```

But it only outputs first line`(Script1)` and the 2nd script stops and doesn't outputs the 2nd line as well, i guess it's because of **goto** line in batch script and i have no idea what can be done here to make it work!

Comment: Is `python2` a batch file? If yes, you need to `call` it, else it will not "return" to your script

Comment: @Stephan no but i'm running a python script through a batch script and it's working well if i delete the spinner code but with the spinner code it's not working as i stated :(

Comment: Your script runs fine, when I replace both `phyton2 ...` lines with `timeout 1 >nul`. (btw: `sleep` is deprecated, so it gives me an error. What Windows version do you use?)

Comment: @Stephan I use windows 7x64 and i don't want any timeout for now and i just wanted to include a waiting spinner till both the script fisnishes their work, any suggestion?

Comment: it will never reach the second python script because of the first `goto` so the second part is never reached. If you remove the first `goto spinner` you'll probably get what you want.

Comment: @Gerhard if i remove the `goto spinner` then the spinner is not working try it yourself :( anonfiles .com/Z6ifPdn8p2/Subdomain_enum_zip

Comment: Should "Script2" start after "Scritp1" is finished or should both scripts run simultaneous?

Comment: @Stephan doesn't matter as long as spinner works and as well as my both the scripts i'm fine with that, but still i prefer '"Script2" start after "Scritp1" is finished'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clarification in your comment, you'd probably want something like this.
We start the commands in separate windows with new window titles per window, then we use `tasklist` to determine of either are still running. So both results will be `echo` if both run, or only one will be `echo`d if only one runs.

```
@echo off
set done1=1
set done2=1

start "enum1" /min cmd.exe /C ^(python2 enumsubdomain.py google.com ^> google.txt^)
start "enum2" /min cmd.exe /C ^(python2 enumsubdomain2.py yahoo.com ^> yahoo.txt^)

:spinner
set mSpinner=%mSpinner%.
if "%mSpinner%"=="...." (set mSpinner=.)
cls
(tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq enum1" | findstr /i "cmd")>nul && echo Enumerating Subdomains From Script1 %mSpinner% || set done1=0
(tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq enum2" | findstr /i "cmd")>nul && echo Enumerating Subdomains From Script2 %mSpinner% || set done2=0
if %done1% equ 0 if %done2% equ 0 goto :eof
(sleep 1)>nul
goto :spinner
```

Comment: no it's not working the script doesn't output anything and spinner acts like that is running under a loop :(

Comment: The spinner works, it use to be a loop to begin with. Maybe explain what you expect to happen with the scripts you are initiating exactly? Are you looking at waiting for them until they are complete?

Comment: Yeah i want the spinner to wait till the script completes it's task :|

Comment: ok, then you're method won't work. batch files work in sequences. Now you're actually just looping each command till the end of time, kicking of the scripts each time. Give me a some time, I will ammend my answer soon, just need to go to the shops and I will help.

Comment: yeah i also think my method is not that good as i have low knowledge of batch scripting so i tried with this broken code :p
okay pal waiting for your answer :D

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the spinner several times, so using a subroutine for the spinner is a good idea.
The main problem is: batch waits for a command to end before continuing with the next one, so you can't include the python command into the loop. Solution: start the command as an independent process and *then* start the "spinning loop". Break it, when the independent process does not exist anymore.

Here the subprocess `:spinner` takes a string as parameter (the message), making it flexible.

Instead of clearing the screen (`cls`) for each iteration of the loop, I took a different approach: overwriting the line over and over (less flickering and keeping the previous screen intact)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM create a CariageReturn:
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"
cls

start /min "MySpinnerProcess" cmd /c "timeout 8 >google.txt"
call :spinner "Enumerating Subdomains From Script1"

start /min "MySpinnerProcess" cmd /c "timeout 5 >yahoo.txt"
call :spinner "Enumerating Subdomains From Script2"

echo finished.
goto :eof

:spinner
tasklist /fi "WindowTitle eq MySpinnerProcess" 2>nul | findstr /bilc:"cmd.exe" >nul || (
  echo %~1 done.
  goto :eof
)
set "mspinner=%mspinner%."
if %mspinner% == .... set "mspinner=."
<nul set /p ".=%~1 %mspinner%   !CR!"
timeout 1 >nul
goto :spinner
```

For completeness my script for running the two scripts simultaneously. (very similar to Gerhard's solution, but keeping two spinners) (in my defense: I already had it ready when I asked you if you want them one after the other or simultaneously, but I just *had* to spend the sunny Sunday Afternoon outside)

```
@echo off
setlocal
::---------Waiting-Spinner---------
start /min "MyPhytonProcess1" cmd /c "timeout 8 >google.txt"
start /min "MyPhytonProcess2" cmd /c "timeout 5 >yahoo.txt"

:spinner
set mSpinner1=%mSpinner1%.
set mSpinner2=%mSpinner2%.
if %mSpinner1%==.... (set mSpinner1=.)
if %mSpinner2%==.... (set mSpinner2=.)
cls
::----------------------------Subdomain-Script-------------------------------
echo Enumerating Subdomains From Script1 %mSpinner1%
echo Enumerating Subdomains From Script2 %mSpinner2%
if "%mSpinner1%%mSpinner2%" == "Done.Done." goto :done
tasklist /FI "WindowTitle eq MyPhytonProcess1" 2>nul |find "cmd.exe" >nul || set "mSpinner1=Done"
tasklist /FI "WindowTitle eq MyPhytonProcess2" 2>nul |find "cmd.exe" >nul || set "mSpinner2=Done"
timeout 1 >nul
goto :spinner

:done
echo finished.
@pause
```